# Vuex + Jest + Composition API: How to check if an action has been called

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vuex, vue-composition-api

I am working on a project built on Vue3 and composition API and writing test cases.

The component I want to test is like below.

`Home.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Child @onChangeValue="onChangeValue" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts>
...

const onChangeValue = (value: string) => {
  store.dispatch("changeValueAction", {
    value: value,
  });
};
</scirpt>
```

Now I want to test if `changeValueAction` has been called.

`Home.spec.ts`

```
...

import { key, store } from '@/store';

describe("Test Home component", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Home, {
    global: {
      plugins: [[store, key]],
    },
  });

  it("Test onChangeValue", () => {
    const child = wrapper.findComponent(Child);

    child.vm.$emit("onChangeValue", "Hello, world");
    
    // I want to check changeValueAction has been called.
    expect(wrapper.vm.store.state.moduleA.value).toBe("Hello, world");
  });
});
```

I can confirm the state has actually been updated successfully in the test case above but I am wondering how I can mock action and check if it has been called.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have sort of a similar setup.

I don't want to test the actual store just that the method within the component is calling dispatch with a certain value.

This is what I've done.

**favorite.spec.ts**

```
import {key} from '@/store';

let storeMock: any;

beforeEach(async () => {
    storeMock = createStore({});
});



test(`Should remove favorite`, async () => {

        const wrapper = mount(Component, {
            propsData: {
                item: mockItemObj
            },
            global: {
                plugins: [[storeMock, key]],
            }
        });
        const spyDispatch = jest.spyOn(storeMock, 'dispatch').mockImplementation();

        await wrapper.find('.remove-favorite-item').trigger('click');
        expect(spyDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(spyDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith("favoritesState/deleteFavorite", favoriteId);
    });
```

**This is the Component method:**

```
      setup(props) {
        const store = useStore();
       
        function removeFavorite() {
            store.dispatch("favoritesState/deleteFavorite", favoriteId);
        }

        return {
            removeFavorite
        }
      }
```

Hope this will help you further :)